# Can a rfid / contactless reader damage a USB flash drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I own a very small usb flash drive I like to carry in my wallet but recently I started using contactless cards (bank, transport) and I'm worried the induction power readers emit might damage / corrupt the flash drive. Could this happen?

Comment: I doubt it. Contactless cards are usually silent (and unpowered); they get powered only for something like a second every time you use it. It seems to be orders of magnitude less energy than a mobile phone, and I have never heard of broken USB keys attributed to proximity with mobile phones.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable argument, and is probably correct, though the nature of the induction to power a rfid chip (small field of relative intensity) vs a phone antenna (not designed to actually power but to reach as far as possible) certainly differs.

Comment: Much more powerful are the devices at registers to burn out the RFID theft-prevention tags; those *can* damage charge card magnetic strips, though a well-constructed USB flash stick probably would be OK.